# Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Am retrieving data from MySQL table using `Android` `HttpURLConnection`
And am getting this error:

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value br of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Error is at this line:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
```

my code:

```
 try {  

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);

        Challenges = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for (int i = 0; i < Challenges.length(); i++) {


            JSONObject c = Challenges.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String trackCoordinates = c.getString(TAG_COORDINATES);

            HashMap<String, String> challengesFromDB = new HashMap<>();

            challengesFromDB.put(TAG_ID, id);
            challengesFromDB.put(TAG_COORDINATES, trackCoordinates);

            ChallengesList.add(challengesFromDB);
        }
```

`.php` file:

```
    $sql = "select * FROM Challenges";

$res=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$result=$array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,array('id'=>$row[0],'userMail'=>$row[1],'trackCoordinates'=>$row[2]));

}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
print json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
```

Maybe error occuring because of my table field:`trackCoordinates` , am storing here googleMaps latitude, longtitude coordinates array,  for example:

```
[lat/lng: (54.892597770959945,23.87877881526947), lat/lng: (54.89242519582151,23.876227363944054), lat/lng: (54.8917038430203,23.877791762351986)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't getting JSON, you're getting html.  Either something on your server is outputting html, or you're hitting the wrong URL.

Comment: I dont get, where is html, because am using php file, which i copied above, file named: retrieveChallenges.php

Comment: Well, I have no idea if you're actually hitting that webpage because you didn't post that code.  But the way PHP works is it outputs data.  Frequently it outputs HTML, to make a webpage.  That output is sent to the client.  Obviously you're trying to make it output JSON, which is fine-  so long as its hitting the correct web endpoint and you aren't outputting any html first.

Comment: Could be something wrong with my php code?For example if I go to sever to that .php file, I see only half of my code: `$row[0],'userMail'=>$row[1],'trackCoordinates'=>$row[2])); } header('Content-Type: application/json'); print json_encode(array("result"=>$result)); mysqli_close($con); `If i go to another my php file, I see nothing, i need to view source to see code